# get laravel csrfToken with useFetch in server side

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js, csrf

i want to know that is there any way to get laravel csrf/sanctum in nuxt SSR mode ? useFetch returns token value just in client side

```
export const useCustomFetch = (url, opts) => {

    const xsrfToken = useCookie('SHOP-XSRF-TOKEN')

    let headers = {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': `application/json`,
        'X-Requested-With': `XMLHttpRequest`,
        ...opts?.headers,
    }

    if (process.client){
        if (xsrfToken && xsrfToken.value !== null) {
            headers['SHOP-XSRF-TOKEN'] = xsrfToken;
        }
    }

    if (process.server) {


        headers = {
            ...headers,
            ...useRequestHeaders(['cookie']),
            referer: 'http://shop.localhost/api'
        }

    }

    return useFetch(url, {
        baseURL: 'http://shop.localhost/api',
        headers,
        credentials: 'include',
        ...opts,
    }
    )

}
```

i tried useing useRequestHeader in process.server but it returns undefined

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with this, but what about getting the token from the `<meta>` tag? Laravel usually has it there in base views.